# после обертки функции в класс перестал итерировать список в шаблоне (django=2.0)

Tags: django

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

import re
from collections import Counter

import urllib.request
import lxml.html



class RssLenta(TemplateView):
    template_name = "rss_lenta.html"

    def soup_parser(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        examplePars = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.example.ru/news/archive')
        dom = lxml.html.fromstring(examplePars.read())
        soup_title = dom.xpath('//div[@class="views-field-title"]/span/a/text()')[:10]
        soup_url = dom.xpath('//div[@class="views-field-title"]/span/a/@href')[:10]
        context = dict(zip(soup_url, soup_title))
        # context_list = sorted(context.items)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'context':context})


def logs_parser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.FILES['file_uploads'].read()
        txt = str(f.decode('utf-8'))

        pattern = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
        ips = re.findall(pattern, txt)
        result = Counter(ips).most_common(10)

        ban = []
        for key, value in result:
            if value > 10:
                ban.append({'ip': key, 'frequency': value})

        return render(request, 'logs_parser.html', {'ips': ban})
    return render(request, 'logs_parser.html')
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path

from . import views
from rss_lenta.views import RssLenta


urlpatterns = [
    path('', RssLenta.as_view()),
    path('logs_parser/', views.logs_parser, name='logs_parser'),
]
```

rss_lenta.html

```
{% extends 'bootstrap4.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block bootstrap4_content %}
<style media="screen">
    .row.mx-auto.d-flex.justify-content-center{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>
<h1 class="pt-3 text-center mx-auto">Последние новости портала sarinform</h1>

<div class="container mt-5">

    <div class="row mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
    {% for key, value in context.items %}
      <a href="https://www.sarinform.ru{{ key }}">{{ value }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, с чего вы взяли,что у вас будет вызываться функция soup_parser ? Окуда django знает про вашу функцию?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView
В классах смотрите наследование и читайте документацию.

---

В вашем случае нужно добавить переменные в функии get_context_data, а потом их использовать в шаблоне

Comment: обернул, тем не менее, не ребит https://pastebin.com/7VLyGwr4

Comment: заменил get_context_data() на get(), и вернул рендером, и всё прилетело, и понял что впринципе cbv для этого не нужно... https://pastebin.com/bZEJawAD